# python3: regex group 1, unexpected result

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to look for a pattern and catch it in python3. For some reason `re.search('(NM_\d+)[^.]', 'NM_000051.3').group(1)` does not return what I expect. The result is "NM_00005" instead of "NM_000051". Can someone explain why?

Comment: you need to remove the negation: `re.search('(NM_\d+)[.]', 'NM_000051.3').group(1)`

Comment: https://regexr.com/

Comment: do you need to make sure the decimal is there? or can you just go until a non-digit (including the decimal) is hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you negate the `.` character with `[^.]` so it matches `1` all right. You need to just *not* negate it to make your group stop just before it.

```
>>> re.search('(NM_\d+)[.]', 'NM_000051.3').group(1)
'NM_000051'
```

same as

```
>>> re.search('(NM_\d+)\.', 'NM_000051.3').group(1)
```

but after all why not let it match until no digits are found?

```
re.search('(NM_\d+)', 'NM_000051.3').group(1)
```

Comment: right, I got it. The 1 is the last digit that can be used to fulfill the non-dot-character condition at the end of my regex. thanks! I've changed it to "\.*" since it can be either a dot (in which case I don't care about the numbers after the dot) or no dot at all.